# How to check table for empty in php

Tags: php

This is my php code for checking whether username exists or not.

```
$link = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
$response = 'no';
if(isset($_POST['username']) && trim($_POST['username']) != ''){
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prochatrooms_users WHERE username = '".mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']))."'", $link);
 if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
  $response = 'yes';
 }
}
echo json_encode(array('exists' => $response));
```

and this is javascript

```
$.customPOST = function(data,callback){
    $.post('templates/default/check_username.php',data,callback,'json');
}
//when typing, the script checks if the username exists
function checkUsername() {
  $.customPOST({username: $('#username').val()},function(r){
    //username exists
    if(r.exists == 'yes'){
     $( "#lay_pw" ).toggle(400,function(){});
    }
    else{
     $( "#lay_pw" ).css("display", "none");
    }

      if(r.exists == 'yes'){
     $('#check').attr('checked', false);
    }
    else{
     $('#check').attr('checked', true);
    }
  });
}
```

this code checked if user was on the username table password field opens
now i want check if the password table was empty password field never opened 
also this is my html form

```
   <form id="login" action="index.php" method="post" name="doLogin" onsubmit="return loginguest();">
<input  type="hidden" name="login" value="1">
<input  id="check" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="isGuest" value="1"  >
       <div>نام خود را در کادر زير وارد کنيد:</div>
 <input name="userName" id="username" value="فقط حروف انگليسي " type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="12" onkeypress="return restrict(event)" onkeyup="checkUsername();" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
       <div id="lay_pw" style="display:none">
        <div>رمز:</div>
        <input name="userPass" id="password" value="" type="password" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if($password == "")
    {
        echo 'Password should not be empty';
        die();
    }
```

and another way is

```
if(empty($password))
    {
        echo 'Password field should not be empty';
        die();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a validation in loginguest function.

```
funciont loginguest (){
  if(document.getElementById('username').value().length === 0){
    alert('Username cannot be empty');
    return false;
  }
  if(document.getElementById('password').value().length === 0){
    alert('password cannot be empty');
    return false;  // to prevent submitting
  }
// ... whatever is in the function
  return true; // to submit form
}
```

Comment: i have a table with username and password column i want check if user1 in username column and if password not null opened password fild in html form if username with null password password fild in html form be opened

Comment: > fild in html form if username with null password password fild in html form be opened - This is what the javascript does. if you want to check whether there is a record in DB you could just count and check result for > 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
$link = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
$response = 'no';
$response_pass = 'no'; //flag for password field
if(isset($_POST['username']) && trim($_POST['username']) != ''){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prochatrooms_users WHERE username = '".mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']))."'", $link);
 if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
  $response = 'yes';
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($query); 
  //checking if password exists for the username. Replace 'password' with the name of the password column from your table
  $response_pass = ($row['password']!=NULL || $row['password']!='')? 'yes' : 'no' ; 

 }
}

echo json_encode(array('exists' => $response, 'pass_exist'=>$response_pass));
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
  function checkPassword() {
    $.customPOST({username: $('#username').val()},function(r){
       //password exists
       if(r.pass_exist == 'yes'){
        // the table contains a password value for this username so do what you need to here
       }
       else{
         // the table DOES NOT contain a password value for this username
       }
   });
 }
```