# Check if username in the table with password in php

Tags: php

I have a table with users name, this table have 2 column (*username* and *password*).
Suppose i have 2 record in this table. For example:

`user1` is username with `1234` for password 
 `user2` with null password

The following code checks if there `username` has a value.

If it has a value: `$response = "Yes"`
If username not exist: `$response = "No"`

Now i want check if `username` exist  with null password , then  set

```
$response="No"
```

Here is my Code

```
$link = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
$response = 'no';
if(isset($_POST['username']) && trim($_POST['username']) != ''){
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prochatrooms_users WHERE username = '".mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']))."'", $link);
 if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
  $response = 'yes';
 }
}
echo json_encode(array('exists' => $response));
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521497/how-to-check-table-for-empty-in-php/21522432 by OP

Comment: where you are checking the password. It will return yes always if username exists and password is what else.

Comment: i have to 2 user types guests and other registered users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add  `AND password !=''`  this line to your query

```
$link = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
$response = 'no';
if(isset($_POST['username']) && trim($_POST['username']) != ''){
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prochatrooms_users WHERE username = '".mysql_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']))."' AND password !='' ", $link);
 if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
  $response = 'yes';
 }
}
echo json_encode(array('exists' => $response));
```

Comment: check the answer i have added that condition to your query

Answer (score 0):

*Well as a first tip, do not use query concatenation when working with SQL. I **strongly** suggest using this approach instead: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Your method makes your login system heavily vulnerable to SQL injections and attackers.*

If you want to check if your password is null, you can try this approach:

```
if ( trim($_POST['password']) == '') {
      $response = 'no';
}
```